# Custom framework cannot find other pod that required Bridging-Header file: "No such module 'InsiderMobile'"

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, bridging-header, module-map

Currently we are developing a custom framework which need to use `InsiderMobile` cocoapods. According to [this guideline](https://academy.useinsider.com/docs/bridging-header-file), we will need o create Bridging-Header File to use InsiderMobile. However, Bridging-Header or Umbrella file did not work inside our framework so we have to use `MapModule` with `Build Settings/Import Paths` method, then the framework compile just fine.

The actual problem occur when we try to apply our framework to an application. The framework recognize all other pods except `InsiderMobile`. Here our current settings:

- We got both our custom framework and InsiderMobile in Pods folder,
- Our custom framework is Embed,
- `MapModule` with `Build Settings/Import Paths` method is also apply,

Here is some methods that we've already tried:

- `pod install` again, delete derived data, clean and rebuild project,
- Manually edit custom framework -umbrella file, but bump into new error: "Include of non-modular header inside framework module ", also try to set `Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules` in `Build Settings` to Yes
- Also Embed `InsiderMobile` framework,

None of these above methods solve the problem. Is there anyway to allow our custom framework to import `InsiderMobile`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's helpful, i have found a way to temporary solve this issue. Not the best but help us unstuck the developing process. Basically, i have been trying to work with `.modulemap` method the whole time, you can find the docs [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-declaration). Then i found [this topic](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7619), and there [this guys repo](https://github.com/bryanboyko/PodFrameworkWithVungleDependency). I just follow the repo with a little change on the `.modulemap` file and everything work fine for me. Here's my `.modulemap` file:

```
module InsiderMobile [system] {
// Framework complier
// header "../../../../Pods/InsiderMobile/InsiderMobile.framework/Headers/Insider.h"

//App complier
header "../../../../../../Pods/InsiderMobile/InsiderMobile.framework/Headers/Insider.h"

export *
```

}

Cause `.modulemap` file directory might change when it go remote, so i have to change to suitable path before deploy it. I know it inconvenience but it work for now.